# During SHA 1 generation FAILURE: Build failed with an exception

Tags: android, android-studio

```
PS C:\Users\IIITU\AndroidStudioProjects\loginpage_9> ./gradlew signingReport--debug 

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'firstversion'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.2.
     Required by:
         project :
         project : > com.android.application:com.android.application.gradle.plugin:8.0.2
         project : > com.android.library:com.android.library.gradle.plugin:8.0.2
      > No matching variant of com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.2 was found. The consumer was configured to find a library for use during runtime, compatible with Java 8, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally, as well as attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '8.0' but:
          - Variant 'apiElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.2 declares a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component for use during compile-time, compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component for use during runtime, compatible with Java 8
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.0')
          - Variant 'javadocElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.2 declares a component for use during runtime, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.0')
          - Variant 'runtimeElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.2 declares a library for use during runtime, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component, compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component, compatible with Java 8
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.0')
          - Variant 'sourcesElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.2 declares a component for use during runtime, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.0')

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

i want to generate SHA1 key when iwm atrying to geneate signingreport it gives me this error please help

Comment: Your `JAVA_HOME` variable most likely points to a Java 11 JRE/JDK but the build process is incompatible with Java 11, it needs a Java 8 JDK. So set the variable so that it points to an a Java 8 JDK and restart the build process.

Answer (score 0):

The Gradle build could not find a compatible version of the Android Gradle Plugin (AGP) for your project. it's looking for a version that is compatible with Java 8 and packaged as a JAR file, but it can only find versions that are compatible with Java 11.

To resolve this issue, you can downgrade your project to use Java 11 or upgrade the AGP version to one that is compatible with Java 8.

You ca do this to downgrading to Java 11:

```
android {
compileOptions {
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }
}
```

Comment: brother i did this still not able to generate SHA key. same error again and again.iam trying to use google signin in my ap for that i need SHA certificate fingerprints. iam getting error failed signing:10